# Could some give an explanation or hint about this kind of equation? $\left(- \sqrt{X^{2} + Y^{2}} + 1\right) \cos{\left (2 \pi X + \phi \right )}$

Tags: 3d

This is a screen shot from an animation generated by [a matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_animation_demo.html)

[image]

the key part in the code is

```
    R = 1 - np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    Z = np.cos(2 * np.pi * X + phi) * R
```

corresponding equation is

$\left(- \sqrt{X^{2} + Y^{2}} + 1\right) \cos{\left (2 \pi X + \phi \right )}$

Could some give an explanation or hint about this kind of equation?

Is there a name of this type of graphics?

usually cosine/sine could generate something like a (half) circle, what does `R` part do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `R` part generates a cone where the point is at (0, 0, 1) and it spreads out below that. It meets the x-y plane at the unit circle:

[image: A cone with the point at (0, 0, 1) and spreading out downward]

The `cos` component defines an extruded cosine wave along the X-axis:

[image: The graph of cos(2*π*x)]

So the final equation takes the cosine wave and multiplies its amplitude by the cone. It will have full amplitude at the origin, and decrease to 0 at the unit circle on the x-y plane. Past that it becomes negative:

[image: Multiplying the second equation by the first]

The `phi` component shifts the sine wave forward or backward along the x axis.