# Why does my code to plot a cone actually generate a roof?

Tags: 3d

per this [post](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/9250/11312), this formula

$Z = 1 - \sqrt{X^{2} + Y^{2}}$

generates a cone where the point is at (0, 0, 1) and it spreads out below that. It meets the x-y plane at the unit circle

[image]

I am trying to reproduce with Python

```
ax = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-1,1.1,.1), np.arange(-1,1.1,.1))
zz = 1 - np.sqrt(xx**2, yy**2)
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, alpha=.5)
```

and get this "roof"

[image]

each of xx, yy, zz is a 21 by 21 matrix, even if I increase them to 210 by 210, nothing changes, what am I missing?

Comment: Looks like your mesh is undersampled, in that it only has 6 vertices so its an approximate cone.. Can you increase the resolution some how ?

Comment: @PaulHK each of xx, yy, zz is a 21 by 21 matrix, even if I increase them to 210 by 210, nothing changes

Comment: What is `np.sqrt(xx**2, yy**2)`? I would expect something like `np.sqrt(xx**2 + yy**2)`. Otherwise you're getting back an array of square roots, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the call to `sqrt` from:

```
np.sqrt(xx**2, yy**2)
```

to:

```
np.sqrt(xx**2 + yy**2)
```

Otherwise you're passing an array of values to the function and will be returned an array of values for the answer.

[See here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html?highlight=sqrt#numpy.sqrt) for details:

> `>>> np.sqrt([1,4,9])`
>
> array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])